# Replacing a procedure in a package (Oracle 11+)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created the package and the package body with procedure successfully.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack_test IS
  PROCEDURE proc_test();
END pack_test;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_test IS
  PROCEDURE proc_test() IS
    ...
  END proc_test;
END pack_test;
```

But when I try to replace this procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pack_test.proc_test() IS
   ..... 
END pack_test.proc_test;
```

I get error:

```
Error report - ORA-01031: Insufficient privileges
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without the necessary privileges
```

But I have grant CREATE PROCEDURE (and I created the package pack_test successfully).

Can I replace procedure in package without modifying and resubmitting the whole package body code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. If you want to replace a procedure inside a package body, you need to replace the body. There is no option to replace a procedure inside a package without replacing the body itself.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_test IS
  PROCEDURE proc_test() IS
    ...
  END proc_test;
END pack_test;
```

Think in a package as a collection of objects ( as procedures and functions ) stored together for functional purposes. When you need to modify a procedure or function inside a package body, you modify the package body by executing the statement **CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY**

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: I need to redifine all package body? There is not other way?

Comment: yes, there is no other way. think in the body as an object like a procedure or function

Comment: in addition to what @RobertoHernandez said, this link will be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652398/replacing-part-of-an-oracle-package

Comment: Hi @Sorand , please accept the answer as valid if you consider so, thereby you will help other users.

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez, how can I do this?